# QGIS Plugin for creating Quality information

Tags: qgis-plugins

I am planning to create a plugin to create quality information. The plugin should do following actions: 1)  To add Dataset for which the quality information is to be added. 2)  View the quality info if available. 3) Create a new one or edit existing. 4)   Save it to the Database along with the dataset. I need to know whether all the tasks mentioned above is possible to create or not. If possible send me the links where I can get ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know how to code in python:

1. Look at the [pygis developer cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/)
2. Look at existing plugins how other people coded their plugins. You can access them in your QGIS profile folder after download or get [them here](http://plugins.qgis.org/) as zip-file
3. Look in the [QGIS API](http://qgis.org/api/index.html) if you can not find the method/function/class you are looking for. (Tip: Search Bar ;) )
4. If they are very specific questions, try to ask a question here and please (!!!) give a code-example. However note that you should only ask questions directly related to PyQGIS and not general python issues. Those belong to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or other websites.